# similar to gem byebug for coffescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, javascript-debugger, byebug

Is there any ***similar tool*** to ruby gem `byebug` for **coffescript**?

I'd like to be able to stop the JS code and check variables' values/statuses (e.g. data, etc)

Comment: If you use chrome, you can use chrome inspector and set breakpoints using this. I expect it to work similarly for firebug etc.

Comment: debug using chrome console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `debugger` as you would `byebug` and make sure you have the browser's developer console open. Execution will pause and you can step through the debugger and peek at the local scope.

See the [documentation on debugger for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)

Comment: Just what I was asking for, thank a lot